# Why do I have,com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, mariadb

I am trying to connect to a database server with SCALA

```
scala> val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
     | "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test",
     | "milenko",
     | "nilton")
```

I got this

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1038)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:338)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2237)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I have just basic knowledge of SQL,I am trying to run this example from scala tutorial

```
scala> val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test",
"root", // username when connecting
"" // password
)
java.sql.Connection = com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12e78a69
```

I have tried this,to find listener on port

```
 netstat -tln

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:31416           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

According to this,I have changed my connection but still get the same.
I search for database

```
milenko@milenko-desktop:~$ netstat -an | grep -i mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     404688   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
milenko@milenko-desktop:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for milenko: 
root@milenko-desktop:/home/milenko# mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 8
Server version: 10.0.29-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Ubuntu 16.04

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I try to change protocol

```
root@milenko-desktop:/home/milenko# mysql --protocol=TCP/IP
Unknown option to protocol: TCP/IP
Alternatives are: 'TCP','SOCKET','PIPE','MEMORY'
root@milenko-desktop:/home/milenko# mysql --protocol=TCP
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111 "Connection refused")
```

How should I specify my root,where is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)

Comment: MySQL isn't running, or at least it is not running on localhost:3306. See the linked duplicate for more information.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Please ,take a look at my edit,I am new to mysql.

Comment: It looks like you only have MySQL running on a unix domain socket; the MySQL JDBC driver can't use that: it can only connect over TCP/IP; change your MySQL config so it listens on 127.0.0.1:3306. See also the accepted answer on the linked duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have have tried to change config,please take alook at my newest edit!